# Configure Widgets with difference content

Tags: android, widget, android-pendingintent

My app creates many widgets of the same type, but with different content. When the user clicks on one widget, it is important to know the `widgetId`, so I know the content to update.

My way seems to be totaly wrong, because my `PendingIntent` gets overridden. So  I always get the same `EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID` instead of n different ones.

Here is my code, the part when I set the PendingIntent for my `OnClick`.

```
// edit intent
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.base_info_widget);
Intent editIntent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
editIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);         
editIntent.putExtra(GlobalVariables.COMMAND_KEY_ACTION,GlobalVariables.COMMAND_VALUE_EDIT);
editIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,appWidgetId);
Log.d(MY_TAG, "putExtra EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID="+ Integer.toString(appWidgetId));
PendingIntent pendingEditIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, editIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.layout_wrapper, pendingEditIntent);
```

I hope my question was clear. How can I solve that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your intent unique:

```
 editIntent.setData(Uri.parse(editIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
```

That's why you get always same id on all widgets

Comment: That was easy! :-) Thank you so much!